# How to create a file with public access

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I need to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage and make it public immediately.
I use `createWriteStream`.
If I try to write a file and after a finish immediately call `makePublic` - I get an error about that no such object.
For now, I use setTimeout with `makePublic` callback, but it's a hacky way.

the code looks like this:

```js
const name = 'folder/file.jpg'
const fileRef = bucket.file(name)

const save = (stream, name, meta) => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stream
      .on('error', (error) => reject(error)})
      .on('end', () => resolve(name))
      .pipe(fileRef.createWriteStream({
        metadata: meta,
      }))
  })

save(yourReadStream(), name, yourMetaObj)
.then(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    fileRef.makePublic()
  }, 1500)
})
```

How to avoid setTimeout and do it in a guaranteed way?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to allow public access at the object level using gsutil.

You can run the following command to change the permission of the object only, and maintain strict permissions on the bucket and other objects within that bucket:

```
gsutil acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]
```

More information this can be [found here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public).

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is to just make the entire bucket public, then you don't need to try and make the individual objects public each time.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/iam#ch

```
gsutil iam ch allUsers:objectViewer gs://ex-bucket
```

Note: This will make *all* objects in the bucket publicly readable. if you have objects in that bucket that you cannot make public, then I recommend creating a separate bucket to hold the public objects.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I decided to switch firebase storage.